# Find defficient nearest neighbours in 3d space

Tags: c, 3d, nearest-neighbor

My input file is a csv file with data structure as follows;

```
5,3.5644,5.4556,3.5665
...
int_id,x_float,y_float,z_float
```

I have a struct which holds id of a point and its three coordinates. I need to find 4 closest struct based on Euclidean distance. I have done it by naive approach but is there any efficient way to implement it ? I read about knn algorithm but it requires external libraries.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

//struct for input csv data
struct oxygen_coordinates
{
    unsigned int index; //index of an atom
    //x,y and z coordinates of atom 
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

//Given the data in a line in a an inputfile, process it to put it in   oxygen_coordinates struct
struct oxygen_coordinates * line_splitter(struct oxygen_coordinates *data, const char *input)
{
    return (sscanf(input, "%u,%f,%f,%f", &data->index, &data->x, &data->y, &data->z) != 7)
            ? NULL : data;
}
//Distance function for two pints in a struct
float getDistance(struct oxygen_coordinates a, struct oxygen_coordinates b)
{
      float distance;
      distance = sqrt((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y-b.y) *(a.y-b.y) + (a.z - b.z) * (a.z - b.z));
      return distance;
} 

//struct for neighbour distance and their indices
    struct nbrs_ind {
    float value;
    int index;
    };

// comparision function for sorting the neighbours -> qsort library
int cmp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    struct nbrs_ind *pa1 = (struct nbrs_ind *)pa;
    struct nbrs_ind *pa2 = (struct nbrs_ind *)pb;
    if ((*pa1).value < (*pa2).value)
            return -1;
    else if ((*pa1).value > (*pa2).value)
            return 1;
    else
            return 0;
}
//main program
int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *stream; // file pointer
    char *line = NULL; //line pointer
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t nread;
    struct oxygen_coordinates * atom_data = NULL; //pointer to oxygen_coordinate struct
    int numatoms = 0; // counter variable for number of atoms

    int i,j,k,p ; // loop initilizers
    //Check for correct number of arguments
    if (argc !=2 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <inputfile> <outputfile>\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //Open the input csv file given in the first argument
    stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (stream == NULL) {
            perror("fopen");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {
            if ((atom_data = realloc(atom_data, (size_t) (numatoms + 1) * sizeof(struct oxygen_coordinates))) == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error not enough memory");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            line_splitter(&atom_data[numatoms], line);
            numatoms = numatoms + 1;
    }
    free(line);
    fclose(stream);

    // All the data is read in memory in atom_data
    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("There are %d atoms in the input file. \n", numatoms);
    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");


   // declare a global array that will hold the 4 nearest atom_data...
   float dist_mat[numatoms][numatoms] ;// create n by n matrix for  distances
    // Create a 2-D distnace matrix        
    for(j=0; j < numatoms; j++){
            for(k=0; k < numatoms; k++) {
                    dist_mat[j][k] = getDistance(atom_data[j], atom_data[k]);
                    printf("%f\t", dist_mat[j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    //now I sort every row from dist_mat and get the closest 4 
    // I need something like as follows
    ////knn(atom_data[query],atom_data,4);//this should return closest 4 points based on  Euclidean distances in atom_data
    free(atom_data);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Closest to what? A particular point? Or do you need to know the four closest neighbours for EACH point? Clarify your question.

Comment: Yours is the (k) nearest neighbor *search* problem.  The [k nearest neighbors (knn) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) requires solving that problem, but it is not an algorithm *for* solving that problem.

Comment: Double post, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695927/knn-implementation-in-3d-space-for-n-closest-neighbours/55733005#55733005) .

Answer (score 2):

One way of improving the performance is to realize that you do not need the actual distance. Comparing the square of the distance is good enough, so you can skip the `sqrt` function call.

Another thing that might, but not necessarily, speed things up is to start with calculating just the x distance. Use the fact that distances are always positive, so if the x distance is longer than the fourth closest points total distance, then there's no need to calculate `(a.y-b.y) *(a.y-b.y) + (a.z - b.z) * (a.z - b.z)`.

If you choose the approach of starting with just the x-values, I would also suggest changing the data structures. Instead of having a struct for each point, use four arrays: `int *x, *y, *z, *indexes;` This will make the code more cache friendly. *(And yes, there are differences between pointers and arrays, but that was not so relevant here)*

The above methods are quite easy tweaks. If you want to go more advanced, you can use this idea.

1. Divide the space into a grid of 3D-boxes.
2. Calculate which points belongs to which box and store that information.

Look at this image:

[image]

For instance, if you have a point in D4, and you want to find the closest four neighbours, and you find a neighbour in D4, then you **know** that there can be no closer neighbour outside the square C3:E5. In the same way, a point in D4 that has a neighbour in D3 cannot have a closer neighbour outside the area B3:F6.

But first thing when optimizing is ALWAYS to identify the bottleneck. Are you sure that this is the problem? You say that you read the data from a file, and reading one line from a file should be WAY slower than calculating the distance.

Comment: True enough, but the OP seems to be asking for a better algorithm, and this just tweaks up his existing one (and also many other algorithms, of course).

Comment: Hi, reading a data from file is not a problem. I have a better implementation for that because I need to change the input file format later which is not a current problem. I just need a quick neatest neighbour search without actually computing the whole distance matrix. And, not taking square root is a great ideal but for some reason I need the distances of closest neigh ours as well but that is problem to be solved later.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the square root inefficiency mentioned, these loops compute the distance of each pair *twice*.

```
for(j=0; j < numatoms; j++){
    for(k=0; k < numatoms; k++) {
        dist_mat[j][k] = getDistance(atom_data[j], atom_data[k]);
        printf("%f\t", dist_mat[j][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

You can **halve** the execution time by computing the distance of each pair *once only*, as

```
for(j=0; j < numatoms-1; j++){
    for(k=j+1; k < numatoms; k++) {
        dist_mat[j][k] = dist_mat[k][j] = getDistance(atom_data[j], atom_data[k]);
        printf("%f\t", dist_mat[j][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And of course, when `j == k` the distance must be `0`.

Comment: I would also use `double`. Borderline unequal distances might be considered equal with the inferior `float`. I never use float unless I *have to*.